# How can i introduce my own permission in a plugin

Tags: cumulocity

I would like to write an plugin for the cockpit app. The feature i would like to add includes also an additional item in the drop-down menu. However i also would like to introduce my own permission. If the role of the user has the permission the item in menu will be shown otherwise not. Is this possible at all? And how does at look like? I checked the online documentation but couldn't find anything about it. I hope someone could help me...

Answer (score 0):

The only way to introduce new permissions is through a microservice in its manifest. With purely UI you cannot add those.

As an alternative you could base your plugin on any property of the user. You probably would than want to have a second plugin to set/manage this for a user.